# Succeed in registering email/password Laravel Firebase authentication, but failed login using said account

Tags: laravel, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, laravel-10

I am using this tutorial for email/password laravel firebase authentication, I'm using Laravel 10: https://medium.com/@GaonLabs/laravel-firebase-authentication-complete-guide-7735a1f83a3d

My Laravel project register form is made data from form and register it into firebase authentication, so maybe it was working fine?

[Register Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y2o3.png)
[Firebase Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTcBj.png)

However,trying to login using said account stored in firebase authentication gave an error of  "credentials do not match" even when caid account and password typed in form was having the same value as stored in firebase authentication. I don't know if it was firebase error setting or laravel error code.

[try login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsitt.png)
[Failed Login with inspection console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42wmR.png)

All of this that I change was:

**config/app.php**

```
return [
   'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
      Kreait\Laravel\Firebase\ServiceProvider::class,
   ])->toArray(),
];
```

**app/Models/Users.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
class User extends Authenticatable {
   use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
   protected $fillable = [
        'uid',
        'role',
        'name',
        'email',
        'username',
        'password',
        'address',
        'phone',
    ];
    public function getAuthIdentifierName() {
        return 'uid';
     }
     public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->uid;
     }
}
```

**app/Firebase/FirebaseUserProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth as FirebaseAuth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Admin;
class FirebaseUserProvider implements UserProvider {
   protected $hasher;
   protected $model;
   protected $auth;
   public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model) {
      $this->model = $model;
      $this->hasher = $hasher;
      $this->auth = app('firebase.auth');
   }
   public function retrieveById($identifier) {
      $firebaseUser = $this->auth->getUser($identifier);
      $user = new User([
         'uid' => $firebaseUser->uid,
         'email' => $firebaseUser->email,
         'name' => $firebaseUser->displayName
      ]);
      return $user;
   }
   public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {}
   public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token) {}
   public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {}
   public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials) {}
}
```

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Firebase\Guard as FirebaseGuard;
use App\Firebase\FirebaseUserProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
   public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::provider('firebaseuserprovider', function($app, array $config) {
            return new FirebaseUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
         });
    }
}
```

**config/auth.php**

```
return [
   `guards` => [
      `web' => [
         'driver' => 'session',
         'provider' => 'firebaseUser',
      ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
   ],
   'providers' => [
      'firebaseUser' => [
         'driver' => 'firebaseuserprovider',
         'model' => App\User::class,
      ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
   ],
];
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth as FirebaseAuth;
use Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Auth;
use App\Models\User;
class LoginController extends Controller {
   use AuthenticatesUsers;
   protected $auth;
   protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
   public function __construct(FirebaseAuth $auth) {
      $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
      $this->auth = $auth;
   }
protected function login(Request $request) {
      try {
         $signInResult = $this->auth->signInWithEmailAndPassword($request['email'], $request['password']);
         $user = new User($signInResult->data());
         $result = Auth::login($user);
         return redirect($this->redirectPath());
      } catch (FirebaseException $e) {
         throw ValidationException::withMessages([$this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],]);
      }
   }
   public function username() {
      return 'email';
   }
public function handleCallback(Request $request, $provider) {
      $socialTokenId = $request->input('social-login-tokenId', '');
      try {
         $verifiedIdToken = $this->auth->verifyIdToken($socialTokenId);
         $user = new User();
         $user->displayName = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('name');
         $user->email = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('email');
         $user->localId = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('user_id');
         Auth::login($user);
         return redirect($this->redirectPath());
      } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
         return redirect()->route('login');
      } catch (InvalidToken $e) {
         return redirect()->route('login');
      }
   }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**(in case the error was something like needs of local database)

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth as FirebaseAuth;
use Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException;
class RegisterController extends Controller {
   use RegistersUsers;
   protected $auth;
   protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
   public function __construct(FirebaseAuth $auth) {
      $this->middleware('guest');
      $this->auth = $auth;
   }
   protected function validator(array $data) {
      return Validator::make($data, [
         'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
         'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
         'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
      ]);
   }
   protected function register(Request $request) {
      $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
      $userProperties = [
         'email' => $request->input('email'),
         'emailVerified' => false,
         'password' => $request->input('password'),
         'displayName' => $request->input('name'),
         'disabled' => false,
      ];
      $createdUser = $this->auth->createUser($userProperties);
      return redirect()->route('login');
   }
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**resources/views/auth/login.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="login" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                {{ __('Username or Email') }}
                            </label>
                        
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="login" type="text"
                                    class="form-control{{ $errors->has('username') || $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                    name="login" value="{{ old('username') ?: old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                        
                                @if ($errors->has('username') || $errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') ?: $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="mb-0">
   <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" onClick="socialSignin('facebook');">
      <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Sign in with Facebook
   </a>
   <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google"  onClick="socialSignin('google');">
      <span class="fa fa-google"></span> Sign in with Google
   </a>
</div>
<form id="social-login-form" action="" method="POST" style="display: none;">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <input id="social-login-access-token" name="social-login-access-token" type="text">
   <input id="social-login-tokenId" name="social-login-tokenId" type="text">
</form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase, all value in var config I hide it with xxxx here due to security reason
var config = {
    apiKey: xxxxxx,
    authDomain: xxxxxx,
    databaseURL: xxxxxxx,
    projectId: xxxxxx,
    storageBucket: xxxxxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxxxxx,
    appId: xxxxxxxxx,
    measurementId: xxxxxxxx
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var facebookProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var facebookCallbackLink = '/login/facebook/callback';
var googleCallbackLink = '/login/google/callback';
async function socialSignin(provider) {
   var socialProvider = null;
   if (provider == "facebook") {
      socialProvider = facebookProvider;
      document.getElementById('social-login-form').action = facebookCallbackLink;
   } else if (provider == "google") {
      socialProvider = googleProvider;
      document.getElementById('social-login-form').action = googleCallbackLink;
   } else {
      return;
   }
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(socialProvider).then(function(result) {
      result.user.getIdToken().then(function(result) {
         document.getElementById('social-login-tokenId').value = result;
         document.getElementById('social-login-form').submit();
      });
   }).catch(function(error) {
      // do error handling
      console.log(error);
   });
}
</script>
```

So did anyone know how to fix this particular error of not matching credentials despite having same value? did I need to recalibrate firebase settings or did some of codes in laravel for login was something different? What I want is I can login using stored/registered account in firebase authentication and redirect it into user homepage.